# Query Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax

Please help me correct the following query:

```
SQL = "insert into tblContract (Empid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, " & _
                    "Start2, Finish2, Store2 ) " & _
      "values ('" & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & _
                    "',select max(testid) FROM tbltesting,'" & _     
                    Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & _
                    Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & _
                    Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & _
                    Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & _
                    Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & _
                    Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "')"
```

Problem is here :

```
select max(testid) FROM tbltesting
```

Any other options ?

Answer (score 2):

Sub-queries should be enclosed in parentheses: `(select max(testid) FROM tbltesting)`

Note that your SQL engine will probably not support sub-queries in the `INSERT` statement, so you should insert using a `INSERT...SELECT` query instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `VALUES`:

```
SQL =  "
       INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2)
       SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" &
       Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & 
       Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & 
       Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' " &
       "FROM tbltesting'"
```

Since you have `7` target fields and `8` `SELECT` list expressions, this won't compile until you provide an extra field in the `INSERT` clause where you want your `MAX(testid)` to go to.

Comment: @Jonathan: it's perfectly possible to put them into the select list just as well

Comment: Could please rewrite the entire query ??

Comment: It is, but you would need to show that in action - especially since the first value in the list is not the value from the sub-query.  It is also complex because you'd have to use a GROUP BY clause citing an 'alias' for each constant.

Comment: Please tell me what details you need ?

Comment: Ok for the below query it says syntax error :


"INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2)  SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" &Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" &Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" &Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' " & "FROM tbltesting'"

Comment: "INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid,testid,Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2) SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" &Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" &Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" &Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' "

Comment: @Jaison: you have 7 target fields and 8 columns. Where you want you MAX(testid) to go to?

Comment: @Jaison: are you sure the query is the reason of the error? What happens if you replace all you fields with literal values?

Answer (score 1):

If anything is going to work, you will have to embed the sub-query inside an extra layer of parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, Col2, Col3)
    VALUES(val1, (SELECT MAX(testid) FROM tbltesting), val3);
```

Be aware that you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.org/327) attacks.

---

Using IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50 in a database with a 'table of elements', the following works:

```
create temp table t(i integer, j integer, k integer);
insert into t values(1, (select max(atomic_number) from elements), 2);
select * from t;

1   118     2
```

This is correct given the current data in the table of elements.

Comment: Note the answer from @onedaywhen: you have a mismatch between the number of columns listed and the number of values provided.  The 'Compile error argument not optional' message might be related to that mismatch.

Comment: no no ..still the query not working ..even i give the same number of columns

Comment: OK - it may be that this construct is not supported by MS Access, then.  It is quite probably a reasonable but non-standard extension of SQL (using a construct that is allowed elsewhere in SQL in a context where the SQL standard does not require it to be allowed).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Given the Access context, please explain how the cited SQL statement is in any way shape or form vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: It depends on what can be put into any of the variables such as `Me.txtContSunStart1.Value`; they seem to be user inputs and if they are not strictly typed, then it could contain text along the lines of the example in the XKCD cartoon.  Any time a user-supplied value is converted to a string (or is treated as a string) and is not protected from misinterpretation, there is a chance of SQL Injection.  There isn't enough code to be sure either way - at least, not to my eyes.  But because there was no self-evident protection when building the SQL statement, there is a chance of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-write your `VALUES` clause as a `SELECT` query.

You have seven columns in your `INSERT` clause and eight in your `VALUES` clause. From the column names I guess your subquery

```
select max(testid) FROM tbltesting
```

is missing a destination. Guessing it may be called `starting_testid`; also guessing data types (Access database engine ANSI-92 Query Mode syntax):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddContract
(
 :Empid INTEGER, 
 :Start1 DATETIME, 
 :Finish1 DATETIME,
 :Store1 VARCHAR(20), 
 :Start2 DATETIME,
 :Finish2 DATETIME,
 :Store2 VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
insert into tblContract 
( 
 Empid, starting_testid, 
 Start1, Finish1, Store1, 
 Start2, Finish2, Store2
)
SELECT :Empid, max(testid), 
       :Start1, :Finish1, :Store1, 
       :Start2, :Finish2, :Store2
  FROM tbltesting;
```

Comment: Well done spotting the mismatch between the number of named columns and the number of values.

Comment: Standard SQL would require a GROUP BY clause when you mix the aggregate and the non-aggregate values in the select-list.  Does that work OK in M Access - or MS SQL Server?

Comment: no no ..still the query not working ..even i give the same number of columns

Comment: "Standard SQL would require a GROUP BY clause when you mix the aggregate and the non-aggregate values in the select-list" -- I'm not sure that's correct. If you replace the parameter values with literals then the Mimer SQL-92 Validator (http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml) says it is entry level SQL-92. The standard for procs is SQL/PSM but I don't know of a validator for that ;) Also, not many SQLs support the SQL/PSM standard, the Access database engine certainly doesn't! :)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: "Does that work OK in M Access" -- I tested it for the Access database engine and it indeed works...

Comment: @Jaison: I've guessed data types and a column name, so the chances of it working are small. Also note you need to put the Access UI into ANSI-92 Query Mode or use an OLE DB connection e.g. ADO code.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Why would you answer an Access question with a reference to Mimer SQL-92 Validator? How is that even remotely relevant?

Comment: I received a comment (Jonathon Leffler) about standard SQL. The Mimer SQL-92 validator tells you whether SQL text complies with any level of SQL-92 Standard SQL. I used the validator to challenge the point about Standard SQL's requirement or otherwise for a GROUP BY clause. So in summary 1) OT perhaps but he started it; 2) I didn't answer a question, I commented on a comment; 3) portability should always be a consideration ;)