# Insert statement with where clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Query Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119246/query-syntax-error)

I want insert value using the below command

```
DoCmd.RunSQL = "insert into tblContract(
 Empid,
 Start1,
 Finish1,
 Store1,
 Start2,
 Finish2,
 Store2)
values ('" & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "','" 
  & Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '"
  & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" 
  & Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" 
  & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" 
  & Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" 
  & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "')"
```

But while inserting it should insert in the row where value of a column(testid) in the same table is max(testid) of another table.

This query not working :

```
SQL =  "
       INSERT INTO tblContract (Empid,testid, Start1, Finish1, Store1, Start2, Finish2, Store2)
       SELECT " & Me.txtEmpNo.Value & "', MAX(testid), '" &
       Me.txtContSunStart1.Value & "', '" & Me.txtContSunFinish1.Value & "','" & 
       Me.txtContSunStore1.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStart2.Value & "', '" & 
       Me.txtContSunFinish2.Value & "','" & Me.txtContSunStore2.Value & "' " &
       "FROM tbltesting'"
```

I am finding an alternative for this . In ms access it gives compile error

Comment: You have to clarify a bit what you mean... You can't insert anything into an existsing row, that would be an update.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119246/query-syntax-error

Comment: You also might want to look at stored procedures or parameterized queries, this would be very unsafe especially if public facing, it's very open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: .Value property should be removed from your SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an INSERT SELECT instead of an INSERT VALUES. such as.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC) SELECT 'A', 'B', MAX(ColumnC) FROM MyOtherTable
```

On another note though, you should NOT build up your SQL as you are. This is prone to SQL Injection. Someone could quite easily enter "; DROP TABLE tblContract" into one of your text boxes!

Comment: Er, Access won't execute multiple statements with the DoCmd.RunSQL command -- it will give you an "invalid characters after end of SQL statement" error message.

Comment: BTW, that doesn't mean you shouldn't validate user input, just that the cited example of SQL injection can't possibly happen within Access (or any form of Jet/ACE, neither of which support batched SQL statements).

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to grab the value from the other table and then used that to insert into this table, you can also use a trigger to do that. Be aware that you can have the same value twice if 2 users execute the same query at the same time...you will need lock the other table in that case...max() is problematic

why not use identity and then the scope_identity() function to grab after you insert into the other table?

you also understand that what you doing is a sql injection attack waiting to happen

Comment: SQL injection on a VBA application can't be that big of a concern.

Comment: Yeah but how long will it be a VBA application? These things often get a life of thier own and get ported

Comment: mgroves, some people do use Access as a web interface. Also, don't you think you should protect your data from disgruntled employees as well as outsiders? SQl Injection doesn't have to come from outside the company. Besides, learning to think about such things as "Is this open to attack" will help this person's career when he moves away from Access.

Comment: Please cite an example of someone using Access as a "web interface." It's a nonsensical assertion, actually, if you use a proper definition of both "Access" and "web interface."

Comment: BTW, in regard to Access SQL Injection, this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512174/non-web-sql-injection hashes it out and shows that in general, there's only a very limited set of vulnerabities, and none involve DDL or updates to data -- they are limited to faking WHERE clauses in SELECT statements that will then return all rows.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly you want

```
INSERT INTO tblContract(col1..., testId) values
    ('value1',..., (SELECT MAX(testID) FROM tblOther));
```

***Be warned*** this may lead to concurrency issues

Comment: This is how I was thinking it needed to be done.

Comment: And then some! This is not a good practice to follow and should be stamped out now! Either know the foreign key value in advance and insert the value with it, or insert both tables in the same transaction.